# Spyder package installed by pip fails to run in ubuntu 17.10

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip, python-3.6, spyder

getting some errors when trying to run spyder (3.2.4) and I am thinking it is because of its install location.

On ubuntu-17.10, using python 3.6.3, I wanted a pip installed version of spyder and using `pip3 install --user spyder` which went with all the other packages in `~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages` and sent the executable to `~/.local/bin`.

Running the `spyder3` executable returns a long list of errors and permission denials.

I have tried installing it by `sudo pip3 install -U spyder` which goes to `/usr/local/bin/` but nothing changes. Also I want the installation in my home folder with the other packages. What have I done wrong? Is this an incorrect way to use spyder?

```
$ ~/.local/bin/spyder3
Failed to write user configuration file.
Please submit a bug report.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/stelios/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/utils/external/lockfile.py", line 150, in lock
    symlink(str(os.getpid()), self.name)
FileExistsError: [Errno 17] File exists: '9449' -> '/home/stelios/.config/spyder-py3/spyder.lock'
```

This was only part of the full error message but it was quite long and I didn't want to clutter the quesion. If you need to see it in full please let me know and I will post it.